# How do I align a UserForm next to the active cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm of a MonthView that opens when I click in the specified range of cells. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700052/position-userform-differently-for-each-activecell-clicked) gave me the basic script. It doesn't put the UserForm where I expect.

Here is the script (that I placed in a specific worksheet) to open the UserForm when I click any cell in range `B3:C2000`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set oRange = Range("B3:C2000")
    If Not Intersect(Target, oRange) Is Nothing Then
        frmCalendar.Show
        frmCalendar.Top = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Top
        frmCalendar.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
    End If
End Sub
```

Question 1: I have the UserForm StartUpPosition property set to `0 - Manual` - is this correct?

Question 2: When I click any cell in the specified range, for the first time after opening the workbook, the UserForm always opens in the far top left corner of the screen. Why?

Question 3: When I click any cell in the specified range, for any clicks after the first, the UserForm opens relative to the previous cell that was active, instead of the one I just clicked.  How do I get it to open relative to the cell just clicked, instead of relative to the previous active cell?

Question 4: Why does it appear to align the bottom of the UserForm instead of the top?

After I do the following steps:
1 - Click cell C15
2 - UserForm opens
3 - Close UserForm
4 - Click cell 16
5 - UserForm opens

This is what I see:

[image: Original result]

**EDIT: Here is the result after implementing J. Garth's solution (and changing the Offset property to (0, 2):**

[image: Correct result]

Comment: Something tells me one of the two sets of coordinates isn't using the unit you'd expect. It would be nice if your screenshot highlighted or pointed out the exact point you're expecting the form's top/left corner to be vs the selected cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1: I have the UserForm StartUpPosition property set to 0 - Manual - is this correct?** Yes, it's correct.  In the code below, I am setting this property in the code.

**Question 2: When I click any cell in the specified range, for the first time after opening the workbook, the UserForm always opens in the far top left corner of the screen. Why?** I think the answer to this is somewhat related to question #3.  That would seem to be a default location for the form to open in.  The way you have the code now, trying to set the form top and left coordinates in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event is not working because the coordinates are never actually getting set.  The setting of the coordinates needs to be moved to the userform initialization event.

**Question 3: When I click any cell in the specified range, for any clicks after the first, the UserForm opens relative to the previous cell that was active, instead of the one I just clicked. How do I get it to open relative to the cell just clicked, instead of relative to the previous active cell?**  This problem is also related to the code being in the wrong place.  As noted above, the coordination setting needs to take place in the userform initialization event.  As to why it's referencing the previous active cell, my guess would be that the active cell doesn't actually get changed until after the worksheet selection change event completes.  So since you are trying to set the coordinates within this event (i.e. - before the event finishes), you are getting the previously active cell.  Again, moving the code to the correct location fixes this issue.

**Question 4: Why does it appear to align the bottom of the UserForm instead of the top?**  There appears to be a difference between the definition of "top" when it comes to cells (ranges) vs userforms.  The top of the cell is measured from the first row whereas the top of the userform seems to be measured from the top of the Excel application.  So in over words, if activecell.top and userform.top are both equal to 144, they will be different locations on the screen.  This is because the top of activecell is 144 points down from the first row in the Excel spreadsheet while the top of the userform is 144 points down from the top of the Excel application (i.e. - the top of the Excel window), which is higher on the screen because the starting point (top of the Excel window) is higher than the starting point for activecell.top (first row in the spreadsheet).  We can adjust for that by adding the height of the userform plus the height of the active cell to the top coordinate.

### Sheet module code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim oRange As Range

    Set oRange = Range("B3:C2000")
    If Not Intersect(target, oRange) Is Nothing Then
        frmCalendar.Show
    End If

End Sub
```

### Userform code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = ActiveCell.Top + ActiveCell.Height + .Height
        .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!  I'm very new to VBA - I can read code and generally follow along, but understanding something like the significance or timing of the initialization event, I am still developing.  I am also still learning how to know where to put each piece of code.  But your explanation was very clear and helps me better understand what is happening.

Comment: @J. Garth This solution will **not** work when the zoom level changes, when you have split/frozen panes and the active cell is a visible cell outside the sheet's initial visible range, etc. The answer is informative, well written and answers the question though. It's just that it doesn't cover the potential follow up problems - but then, few bits of code on the internet on this subject do, to be fair...

Comment: @YinCognyto Those are good points. However, my understanding of the purpose of SO is that it is a place to get answers to specific coding problems. It's not meant to be a "consider all of my business use cases for me, and write complete code to handle them" site. The problem presented was solved and the solution provided enough info about how userforms and positioning works to allow someone to do some research and write further code to handle various circumstances. If a person got stuck trying to extend the code, I imagine they could open a new topic and reference this page and ask for help.

Comment: @J. Garth You are correct, of course. I'll provide an answer to cover pretty much everything about such an issue anyway, if not for being thorough, at least for the fact that I myself spent quite a while gathering bits of code and useful information from a multitude of sources until I managed to assemble a complete solution to use in my not so light workbook. It would be good to have such a solution that works everytime, so that other users don't have to navigate through dozens of pages and figure the math on each one of those for themselves - considering the scarcity of the info on the topic.

Comment: @YinCognyto Awesome.  I think that would be really helpful.

Comment: @J.Garth Ok then - will do. Just so you know, I'm not looking to steal your accepted answer by any means. Just trying to potentially help others from going the lengthy rout I went ;)

Comment: @YinCognyto Thanks for being concerned about it.  It's nice when people consider those types of things.  :)  And thanks for taking the time to expand on the topic.  I think it will help a lot of people as this seems to be a difficult area to get right and you will probably save people from rework if their users create any of the conditions you listed and then encounter problems.

Answer (score 8):

The answer provided by J. Garth did a *great* job explaining things, however, as I mentioned in my comments, while it works for this specific situation, it fails on various other scenarios (e.g. zoom level changes, split/frozen panes with the target range outside the sheet's initial visible range), not to mention that it doesn't take into account the header row/column (that are also subject to zoom level changes) and the 3D "frame/border" around a form when setting the position.

I spent a few days looking for a complete answer to cover all possibilities, and the **only** one that set a form's position very close to the correct one in almost all scenarios was [this one](https://github.com/nervgh/vba/blob/master/GetRectForExcel2007Plus/test.xlsm_VBProject/mod_GetRectForExcel2007Plus.bas) by nerv, written as a result of [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/645bc25d-1fbe-4324-839a-9f4f2b58f697/activewindowpointstoscreenpixelsx-pointstoscreenpixelsy-requires-pixels-not-points-and-requires?forum=exceldev) on MSDN forums - most of the credit goes to him, obviously. I "merged" it with other bits of information and code from various other sources in order to avoid hardcoded variables, make the code 32bit and 64bit compatible and cover the mysterious 3D frame around the form issue.

**Sheet code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

**Userform code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim pointcoordinates As pointcoordinatestype, horizontaloffsetinpoints As Double, verticaloffsetinpoints As Double
    With Me
        horizontaloffsetinpoints = (.Width - .InsideWidth) / 2
        verticaloffsetinpoints = 1 
        Call GetPointCoordinates(ActiveCell, pointcoordinates)
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = pointcoordinates.Top - verticaloffsetinpoints
        .Left = pointcoordinates.Left - horizontaloffsetinpoints
    End With
End Sub
```

**Module code**

```
Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88
Private Const LOGPIXELSY = 90
Public Type pointcoordinatestype
    Left As Double
    Top As Double
    Right As Double
    Bottom As Double
End Type
Private pixelsperinchx As Long, pixelsperinchy As Long, pointsperinch As Long, zoomratio As Double
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub ConvertUnits()
  Dim hdc As LongPtr
    hdc = GetDC(0)
    pixelsperinchx = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) ' Usually 96
    pixelsperinchy = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY) ' Usually 96
    ReleaseDC 0, hdc
    pointsperinch = Application.InchesToPoints(1)   ' Usually 72
    zoomratio = ActiveWindow.Zoom / 100
End Sub

Private Function PixelsToPointsX(ByVal pixels As Long) As Double
    PixelsToPointsX = pixels / pixelsperinchx * pointsperinch
End Function

Private Function PixelsToPointsY(ByVal pixels As Long) As Double
    PixelsToPointsY = pixels / pixelsperinchy * pointsperinch
End Function

Private Function PointsToPixelsX(ByVal points As Double) As Long
    PointsToPixelsX = points / pointsperinch * pixelsperinchx
End Function

Private Function PointsToPixelsY(ByVal points As Double) As Long
    PointsToPixelsY = points / pointsperinch * pixelsperinchy
End Function

Public Sub GetPointCoordinates(ByVal cellrange As Range, ByRef pointcoordinates As pointcoordinatestype)
  Dim i As Long
    ConvertUnits
    Set cellrange = cellrange.MergeArea
    For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Panes.Count
        If Not Intersect(cellrange, ActiveWindow.Panes(i).VisibleRange) Is Nothing Then
            pointcoordinates.Left = PixelsToPointsX(ActiveWindow.Panes(i).PointsToScreenPixelsX(cellrange.Left))
            pointcoordinates.Top = PixelsToPointsY(ActiveWindow.Panes(i).PointsToScreenPixelsY(cellrange.Top))
            pointcoordinates.Right = pointcoordinates.Left + cellrange.Width * zoomratio
            pointcoordinates.Bottom = pointcoordinates.Top + cellrange.Height * zoomratio
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Most of the things above are self-explanatory, and they work flawlessly - at least from what I've been able to test. The only thing that still bothers me a bit (yeah, I know, but I'm a perfectionist) is that for some reason the form frame isn't ***exactly*** on the desired cell gridline (i.e. it's 1px lower) for odd numbered rows (while it all goes smooth for even numbered ones). If anyone can figure out why, please share this mystery with me, as I doubt that it's a simple rounding issue...

*EDIT*: Today, while working with Timers, I figured out how to avoid the differences between odd and even numbered rows that occured above: it was just a matter of declaring point values and outputs (as well as the zoom ratio) `As Double` (i.e. floating-point numbers) instead of `As Long` (i.e. integers). Silly mistake from my part - I've properly edited the code to correct it. I've added a `verticaloffsetinpoints` variable to adjust the curious (but this time consistent) "1px lower than expected" vertical glitch that I couldn't find an explanation for (yet).

Comment: Great second answer, and an excelent teaching comment discussion on the topic of what to post,... I like the way that you referenced your major source, normally, one would copy enough of the code to be directly informative, but. In your case you wrote new code and made it clear to the reader  kudos to the OP for a clear question. @YinCognyto

Comment: Also kudos to the first answer!  @J. Garth

Comment: @ElderDelp I'm glad you liked it, and it's even better if it helped you ;) I believe that **the least** one deserves for providing the results of his work for free is to be given proper credit for it - hence the references. As for being thorough, it's also because *I actually needed* the right code for this myself, in my workbook, where I have freezed panes, an `InkPicture` control to [detect changes in the zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422870/event-triggered-with-activewindow-zoom-event-holding-ctrlmouse-wheel), etc., so (re)positioning the form accordingly was critical.

Comment: It's just epic post! Thank you very much and of course for **nerv**. It's very suprisingly that his orginal code with hardcoded values is very simple vanilla VBA without WinAPI. It's even better to store your code in some custom UserForm class to handier reusability. Regards

Comment: @RafałB. Thanks for the appreciation, and of course you're right. The original code was of great help for me too, but due to the specifics in my case I had to improve and add to it a bit. It certainly does its job, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the GetDeviceCaps , GetDC , ReleaseDC functions in Module1, I aligned the userform next to the clicked activecell .(I checked the codes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Excel)

[image]

```
Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hDc As LongPtr) As Long
    Dim hDc As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDc As Long) As Long
    Dim hDc As Long
#End If
...
```

[Source of codes & sample file](https://eksi30.com/add-date-to-cell-easily-with-excel-userform/#excel_place_userform_next_to_activecell)