# Event triggered with ActiveWindow zoom event (holding CTRL+Mouse wheel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a dashboard and need to have zoom level set to `100%`. So whenever User tries to Zoom using mouse wheel button or Zoom level option, I need to catch that event and return Zoom to `100%`. I have searched all over internet for answer and found that there is no such thing as OnZoom event.

- There is an option to check zoom level every few milliseconds and
  restore it to 100%, but i can't accept this cause of rounding circle
  appearing on mouse arrow constantly, which is distracting.
- Hiding Zoom control is also not an option since user can still zoom
  with CTRL+MouseWheel.
- Using Class modules also work only on manual selecting zoom level
  from menu `View > Zoom`
  [solution](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=49551)

All answers I found were dated more than 5 years ago, so maybe in the meantime someone found a solution or this feature is added in newer versions of Excel?

Any lead will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution while playing with ActiveX controls, so for everyone who stumbled on this please find answer below.

First, insert ActiveX control named `InkPicture control`.

Resize control across whole Worksheet visible area.

In worksheet module, paste this code.

```
Private Sub InkPicture1_Resize(Left As Long, Top As Long, Right As Long, Bottom As Long)
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
End Sub
```

For some reason (hope someone can explain why?), when zooming occures, it triggers InkPicture_resize event!
You can also set InkPicture `visible property` to `false`, and it will still works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Zooming triggering the control's resize event might be due to the control being formatted to 'Move and size with cells'. And since the Ink Picture control is apparently the only one having a resize event, well, it suits the scenario perfectly. By the way, the control doesn't have to be resized over the whole worksheet visible area. I made mine a bit smaller than a cell (10x10 is too small to be triggered by all zoom values, but 20x20 will do just fine). It didn't work in invisible mode, so I let it visible - its background color can be set to be the same as the cell anyway.

Comment: While this works as expected, for some reason it messes with the position of other shapes and regular form controls that you may have on the sheet.