# How to set an event when zoom is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set an event that it is triggered when the zoom on the sheet is changed.

In particular, I would like to make column width autofit in a range with the following code.

```
Range("A1:M27").Columns.AutoFit
```

In fact, if the zooom on the sheet change (ActiveWindow.Zoom), some cells may become #######.

Comment: Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422870/event-triggered-with-activewindow-zoom-event-holding-ctrlmouse-wheel].  It's a bit of a fudge but might help.  Or you could set your cells to Shrink to Fit?

Comment: yeah, I saw the answer you redirected me to and I think it might work, but I am not sure  of the steps. I just copy the code in MicrosoftExcelobjects->ThisWorkbook but nothing change. i suppose it is something about the ActiveX but I am not very used to them so I do not know how to proceed

Comment: And, after trying, also the shrink to Fit should be activated everytime the zoom is changed

Comment: There is no built in event.  The problem you have is that something might look fine on your screen, but another user with a different resolution might still have issues.  You can resize the Application or Workbook window, drop it onto a different monitor, etc.  You won't catch every instance.  Shrink to Fit is far safer.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I think I'll stick with Skrink to Fit then