# How to run automatically the zoom lock code after reopen the Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, zooming

Using the following code inside VBA Excel it is possible to lock the zoom of worksheet. But the bad news is that this code is not automatically being run after reopening the Excel file.

Is there any way to run the code without referring to it every time we open the excel file?

Thank you

```
Sub LockZoomInExcel()
 Do
  If ActiveWindow.Zoom <> 100 Then
   ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
  End If
  DoEvents
 Loop While True
End Sub
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

Comment: @user11222393 I tried it but excel file takes a loooong time to open and then nothing happened. Zoom is working

Comment: What do you think `Loop While True` does? You are caught in an endless loop. Excel will wait until the macro is completed, but it never completes.

Comment: @FunThomas by the way it works as regular. But once I wanna force it to open automatically I fail. Any help plz?

Comment: @FunThomas I write a statement inside this Do…Loop to force VBA to reset the zoom to a defined value the moment anyone changes it

Comment: Just saw that I misread your code (because of the missing code indentation). Yes, it works, more or less. The cost is 100% CPU usage of one core.

Comment: @FunThomas I donot have pro knowledge about it. If you have any solution for my problem I will be happy an appreciate your help. This is a code just for my personal data arrangement in Excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(1)** Your routine implements a "busy wait" loop. That means it runs endless, checking if the zoom was changed. If yes, it sets it back to 100%. Then an `DoEvents` is triggered, giving Excel the possibility to handle user input.

This loop runs as fast as the computer can execute it (on my computer, > 10.000 times a second) and keeps the CPU busy (at least one core of it), which will consume energy and will slow down the computer. If you ask me, you should avoid such "busy wait" loops.

**(2)** When you start your code in the `Workbook.Open`-event, the loop is started immediately. The `DoEvents` are not sufficient to let Excel finish the workbook, Excel will wait until the routine is done - which is *never* because it is an endless loop.

**(3)** If you can live with the high CPU usage, use the `OnTime`-method to call the routine after a certain time, e.g. 10 seconds. This should give Excel enough time to finish the process of opening the file. Put the following line into the `Workbook`-module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10), "LockZoomInExcel"
End Sub
```

**(4)** The Excel application object exposes quite a lot of events, but no `OnZoom`, so no way to catch the zoom event.

**(5)** https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423788/7599798 suggests to place a InkPicture ActiveX control and use the `Resize`-event of that. While that sounded promising, it didn't work for me (no event was fired).

**(6)** Best alternative I found was to use the `OnTime`, calling it every second. Put this in a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim nextZoomCheck As Date
Sub checkZoom()
    If ActiveWindow.Zoom <> 100 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    nextZoomCheck = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime nextZoomCheck, "checkZoom"
End Sub

Sub stopCheckZoom()
    If nextZoomCheck = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.OnTime nextZoomCheck, "checkZoom", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Now you can call the `checkZoom`-routine from the `Workbook_Open`-event routine.

You can stop the zoom checking by calling `stopCheckZoom`, maybe when a button is clicked or at a `Worksheet`, or stop it at `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` and start it again at `Workbook_SheetActivate`

Comment: Thank you. I think It works but with this code we can scroll the page down.

Comment: If you want to limit scrolling, use `Worksheet.ScrollArea`, eg `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ScrollArea = "A1:F50"`